# x axis on top of graph in gnu plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm able to put an x axis on the top of a graph in gnu plot via

`set x2label "label"` and 
`set x2tics`

I have a column of data of `data1` values and I'd like to plot these values multiplied by two on the upper x axis against data `data2` in the lower x axis. Both `data1` and `data2` are in the same data file. Here is some sample data

```
data2     data1
20        1.2e-2
40        3.0e-3
60        1.4e-3
...          ...
```

I'd like to plot 2*data1 on upper axis against data2 on lower axis. Preferably, I'd like to just put a tick mark on the 2*data1 axis for every data2 value. On the y axis I will plot some other quantity against data2 but all I want to ask about here is how to plot x2 versus x1.

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about plotting two columns 1 and 2 from the same data file or do you mean two columns from two different files `data1` and `data2`? Please provide a few lines of sample data and explain again which column you would like to multiply and which columns you want plot against which other columns on which axes.

Comment: @theozh done, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. In a 2D-plot, you plot data `y` vs. `x`, i.e. `y1` or `y2` vs. `x1` or `x2`. What do you mean with plotting `x1` vs. `x2`? Do you want to have linked `x1` and `x2` axes? Where is your `y` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still guessing what exactly you want. Maybe we'll find out faster with this example.

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# x2  x1      y
20    1.2e-2  1
40    3.0e-3  2
60    1.4e-3  3
EOD

set key top center
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics nomirror

plot $Data u ($1*2):3 axes x2y1 w lp pt 7 title "y-data vs. x2-axis", \
      '' u 2:3 axes x1y1 w lp pt 7 title "y-data vs. x1-axis"
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

You can link `x1` and `x2` axes via a function (in the example below conversion between nm and eV) and then set your `x2tics` as desired.

1. Graph1: corresponding "odd" values from `x1`,
2. Graph2: "even" values by given interval `x2tics 0.2`,
3. Graph3: manual setting of `x2tics`.

Example:

```
### linked axes x1, x2
reset session

set xlabel "Wavelength / nm"
set xtics nomirror
set x2label "Energy / eV"
set x2tics nomirror
set link x via 1239.8/x inverse 1239.8/x

set ylabel "Intensity / a.u."
set ytics 0.2
set samples 400
Spectrum(x) = exp(-(x-500)**2/(400))

set xrange[380:780]

set multiplot layout 3,1
    set format x2 "%.2f"
    plot Spectrum(x) w l title "Spectrum"

    set format x2 "%.1f"
    set x2tics 0.2
    replot

    set x2tics ()
    myTics = "1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.1 2.3 2.5 2.7 3.0"
    do for [i=1:words(myTics)] { set x2tics add (word(myTics,i) real(word(myTics,i))) }
    replot

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes I think it's close to what I want - although all I'd like to do really is to just put tick marks on the upper axis for each value of 2*x2 and then show on the bottom x axis the corresponding value of x1. E.g I'd have a tick  mark on the upper axis at 2*20 = 40 and then this would correspond to a tick mark on the lower axis of 1.2e-2.  Is it possible?

Comment: well, that's what I meant with linked x1 and x2 axes. However, if 2*20 corresponds to 1.2e-2, and 2*60 should correspond to 1.4e-3, this no linear relationship. What is your relationship between `x1` and `x2` axes? Is it `1/x` or something else?

Comment: Oh I see. Yup one quantity is the inverse of the other up to an overall constant. The data as presented is not precisely the true data, but if it’s needed I can post some sample data in the OP. Thanks! Is it possible to put tick marks on each axis as described in my last comment?

Comment: You can link axes and then you have several ways to set your `x2tics`, see modified answer.

Comment: Thanks! probably the 1st plot is the one i need, i.e a tick mark on the upper axis for every tick mark on the lower one. Where about in the code is it understood a tick mark has to go on upper axis for every tick mark on the lower axis?

Comment: this is also my understanding. You can also add minor tics only on the upper axis, e.g. `set mx2tics 2`

Comment: I suppose the line ‘set link x via 1239.8/x inverse 1239.8/x’ is responsible for setting the values on the top axis... how to modify this line to plot 2*data1 vs data2, where data1 and data2 are columns of data in a file?

Comment: For linking axes, you need a function which describes the relation between `x1` and `x2` axes, e.g. `1/x` or `sqrt(x)` or `x**2` or others. I don't think you can do this via data. But you said that your `x2`-axis is related to `x1`-axis somehow via `c/x`. But if you don't know this relationship, how can you set corresponding tics on both axes?

Comment: I see. The relationship is `x2=2*c**2/(2*x1**2-c**2)`, where `c=1.548458`. I have plotted log x on the lower axis too via `set log scale x`  `set format x "10^{%L}" `. Does it interfere with the procedure you outlined? I managed to get two values of x2 on my upper axis, namely 10 and 100 but clearly for x1=10,100, x2 is much smaller. Not sure what's going on there. Wish the documentation was clearer on these issues.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `x2=2*c**2/(2*x1**2-c**2)` with `c=1.548458` and with `set range [30:2000]` but nothing shows up on my x2 axis. Can you please try it on  your end and see? I believe the following should be ok: `set range [30:2000]` `set link x2 via 2*(1.548458)**2/(2*x1**2-(1.548458)**2) inverse sqrt((2*1.548458)**2*(2+x)/2/x)` `set x2tics` `set xtics nomirror`

Comment: Trying with `set tics mirror` and `set x2tics mirror` at least gives me tics on the x2axis but still no numbers. Also trying with your simple inversion formula gives me `inf` on the upper axis which makes no sense for `set xrange [30:2000]`. May post another question as I'm unable still to get this seemingly trivial thing to work.